# Creating a box-plot based on raster values in ArcMap?

Tags: raster, arcmap, workflow

I'm currently working on ArcMap and having trouble designing my workflow.

My objective is to create a boxplot based on raster values. I want to divide my raster file based on some polygons I have and then for each category create a boxplot.

I thought of zonal statistics as a table but that doesn't show all my values.

Answer (score 1):

**For dividing your raster files**: maybe you could use the Clip raster by polygon/raster clip tool in Data Management of ArcToolbox/Image Analysis Toolbar can clip rasters as well. The main advantage of the Image Analysis Toolbar is that you can visualize the end result before you export it.

**For creating boxplot:**

1. Click the Tools menu, point to Graphs, then click Create Graph Create A New Graph.
2. Click the Graph type drop-down arrow and choose the Box Plot type.
3. Click the Layer/Table drop-down arrow and choose the layer or table containing the data values that are to be graphed.
4. Click the Value field drop-down arrow and choose the field of values to graph. The wizard shows the initial version of the graph. By default, the box plot does not have a legend. You can add a legend to the graph by checking the Add to legend check box. To show the data values in the graph, check the Show labels (marks) check box. You can change the color of the markers on the graph with the Color control.
5. Use the Whisker length control if you want to change the standard threshold beyond which data values are considered outliers.The defaults to value of the whisker length is 1.5, which means that values beyond 1.5 times the length of the box (interquartile range, or where the middle 50% of the data values lie) are determined to be outliers.
6. You can change the appearance of the box plot with the Symbol properties tabs.
7. Use the Box tab to change the size of the box shape of the graph (relative to the total graph area) and its fill color.
8. With the Mild outlier and Extreme outlier tabs, you can control the size and shape of the outlier symbols. The fill color of polygonal shapes is determined by the Color control. 
   The Whisker tab is used to alter the thickness, style, and color of the whiskers of the box plot.
9. Click the Next button to proceed to the general properties page to complete your graph.

References: ArcGIS help for desktop

Comment: it works for any geographic data layer (feature dataset, layer, integer raster) or table.